# Keras batch_size problem when using model.fit in custom layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a custom layer which reshapes the input tensor, perform some dot products with kernels and returns back a tensor with the same number of dimensions . 
The input to my network is images, say of size 61x80.  When the number of train images is a multiple of batch_size , model.fit works fine. eg total train images= 2700, batch_size=10.
But when the total train images =2701, batch_size() it doesnt work, throwing an error something like this-

> > Epoch 1/5 2520/2701 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.7465 - acc: 0.2516Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 5, in 
>       history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=10, epochs=5)
>
> File
>   "/home/eee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1039, in fit
>       validation_steps=validation_steps)
>
> File
>   "/home/eee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py",
>   line 199, in fit_loop
>       outs = f(ins_batch)
>
> File
>   "/home/eee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 2715, in **call**
>       return self._call(inputs)
>
> File
>   "/home/eee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 2675, in _call
>       fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
>
> File
>   "/home/eee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1439, in **call**
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>
> File
>   "/home/eee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py",
>   line 528, in **exit**
>       c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 4880 values,
>   but the requested shape has 48800      [[{{node my_layer_3/Reshape}} =
>   Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_2_0_0,
>   my_layer_3/stack)]]

please help how to get around this problem.

Edit :- Adding the code of the custom layers

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    print(len(input_shape))
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
    assert len(input_shape) >= 3
    input_dim = input_shape[1:]
    print(input_shape)


    self.kernel1 = self.add_weight(shape=self.output_dim[0],input_dim[0]),
                                   name = 'kernel1',
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
    print(self.kernel1)

    self.kernel2 = self.add_weight(shape=self.output_dim[1],input_dim[1]),
                                   name = 'kernel2',
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
    print(self.kernel2)


    super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  

def call(self, x):
     print(x.shape)
     input_shape=x.shape

     mat1_shape =K.int_shape(self.kernel1)     
     mat2_shape =K.int_shape(self.kernel2)

     output1 = Myoperation(x,self.kernel1,1)
     output2 = Myoperation(output1,self.kernel2,2)                

     return output2


def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

    return (input_shape[0],self.output_dim[0],self.output_dim[1])
```

The code for Myoperation function is-

```
def Myoperation(x,mat,mode):
    shape1 = K.shape(x) 
    mode_list =[0,1,2]
    mode_list.remove(mode)
    mode_shape= shape1[mode]

    new_shape = tf.stack( [mode_shape,(shape1[mode_list[0]]*shape1[mode_list[1]])])                    
    input_reshaped = K.reshape(x, new_shape)
    ten_mul = K.dot(mat,input_reshaped)
    out_mode=K.int_shape(mat)
    if (mode==1):
       out_shape =  tf.stack([shape1[mode_list[0]],out_mode[0],shape1[mode_list[1]]])
    if (mode==2):
       out_shape = tf.stack([shape1[mode_list[0]],shape1[mode_list[1]],out_mode[0]])

    output_reshaped = K.reshape(ten_mul,out_shape)    

   return output_reshaped
```

The problem is coming in reshaping the tensor when the train image set is not a multiple of batch_size.

Comment: Please show the code of your custom layer

Comment: Added the code for the custom layer. Please suggest what is wrong